# Trying to mount a Lustre filesystem in a pod: tries and problems

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

For our data science platform we have user directories on a Lustre filesystem (HPC world) that we want to present inside Jupyter notebooks running on OpenShift (they are spawned on demand by JupyterHub after authentication and other custom actions).

We tried the following approaches:

- Mounting the Lustre filesystem in a privileged sidecar container in the same pod as the notebook, sharing the mount through an EmptyDir volume (that way the notebook container does not need to be privileged). We have mount/umount of Lustre occur in the sidecar as post-start and pre-stop in the pod lifecycle. Problem is that sometimes when we delete the pod umount does not work or hang for whatever reason, and as EmptyDirs are "destroyed" it flushes everything in Lustre because the fs is still mounted. A real bad result...
- Mounting the Lustre filesystem directly on the node and create a hostPath volume in the pod and a volumeMount in the notebook container. It kind of works, but only if the container is run as privileged, which we don't want of course.
  We tried more specific sccs which authorize the hostPath volume (hostaccess, hostmount-anyuid), and also made a custom one with hostPath volume and 'allowHostDirVolumePlugin: true', but with no success. We can see the mount from the container, but even with everything wide open (777), we get a "permission denied" with whatever we try to do on the mount(ls, touch,...). Again, it works only if the container is privileged. Does not seem to be SELinux related, at least we have no alerts.

Does anyone see where the problem is, or has another suggestion of solution we can try?

Comment: Are talking about the `--privileged` flag in docker for example?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that for the hostPath to work we have to run the container in Privileged mode (--privileged). Which we don't want as it would give users, who have access to the container through terminal view in Jupyter, full control of the host.

Comment: Could you please share with information what cloud provider you are using?

Comment: Everything is internal, Openshift 3.11 on bare metal.